# minimum of infima of correlated random variables

Tags: probability

Given a set of positive r.v. $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ that are correlated and with probability 1 satisfy the condition
$$
M < \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
is it true
$$
\min_{1 \leq i \leq n} \inf X_i > {M \over n}
$$

My intuition is that, if the infima can be chosen below $M/n$, it may happen with non-zero probability that each and every $X_i$ takes a value so close to its respective infimum that their sum falls below M.

Comment: I guess: the minimum of each random variable may fall below $\frac {M} {n}$. For a simple case where $n = 2$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are so negatively correlated such that if one fall below $\frac {M} {2}$, then the other has to be larger than it almost surely. So maybe marginally it can happen for each but from they cannot happen together for many of them almost surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BGM's comment gave a counterexample where the the correlation was negative, but it is easy enough to give a counterexample where the correlation is positive.

Suppose $(A,B)$ can take the values $(1,2), (2,1), (3,4), (4,3)$ with equal probability.

Then the correlation between $A$ and $B$ is $+0.6$, while $A+B \gt 2.5$.

But $A$ and $B$ can each take values of $1$ (not simultaneously) and $1 \lt \frac{2.5}{2}$.